# jquery ui tooltip / bootstrap tooltip /popover can't make it work withtout title attribute

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I guess I am dumb as **** but I can't make it work without specifing the title attribute.
Here is my code:

```
$('.js-client-info').popover({html : true, title: "ZOMG", content:"asdasdasdasdasdasd"});
```

**Not working**

```
$('.js-client-info').tooltip({html : true, title: "ZOMG", content:"asdasdasdasdasdasd"});
```

**Not working**

Rendering the following:

```
<a class="js-client-info" data-original-title="" title="">gg</a>
```

If I go and place the title attribute on the markup everything works ok. But i want to use the content property and load information with ajax calls. Help me please.

By not working I mean:

- popup never shows even if i call it with code $('.js-client-info').tooltip('show')

Comment: jQuery UI tooltip default functionality is simply - $('.element').tooltip(); which will grab the title attr and display it. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: why do I have the options "title" and "content" then when creating the tooltip? I want to place html inside the tooltip and I don't want to put html in a title tag.

Comment: Oh ok i'll update my answer with something for you ok

Comment: A fiddle here would help us understand the issue better: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nzgdv/1/ here is the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/nzgdv/2/

The issue was fixed by specifying the `items` option.

What the jquery UI tooltip does is replace the browser's default tooltip.

So, I would assume it doesn't automatically work with items that don't have `title` properties (which causes the default tooltip to show).

This is also in the documentation:

> The items and content options need to stay in-sync. If you change one of them, you need to change the other.

Comment: OK MAN! You are great. I tried with items but I never would have thought of placing the wrapping element inside :D Makes no sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what you tried but, basically, the items option tells tooltip which elements it should bind itself to and then the content option tells it what to show. So, it does make sense. =P

Comment: The OP thought that `items: "title , data-html"' would probably work. ?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI tooltip default functionality is simple as cake :D

Basic jQuery:

```
$(function() {
 $('.js-client-info').tooltip();
});
```

For additions to the events and so forth you would do this

```
 $(function() {
   $('.js-client-info').tooltip({
     show: {
    effect: "slideDown",
    delay: 250
  },
    hide: {
     effect: "slideUp",
   }
     });
 });
```

Here is for custom content:

http://jsbin.com/uwuwuk/1/edit

```
$(function() {
   $('.tip').tooltip({
     show: {
    effect: "slideDown",
    delay: 250
  },
    hide: {
     effect: "slideUp"
   },
     items: "[title], [data-html]",//call the attr inside square brackets
     content: function() {
     var element = $( this );
       var call = $(this).attr('data-html'); //var call is same as items though we need to do this
      var randHTML = {a:'<div class="red"></div>',b:'<div class="blue"></div>'};//array of html (technically objects)
    if ( element.is("[data-html]") ) {
      return randHTML[call]; //if element is data-html return the randHTML with which attr it has (a, b, c, d)
    }
    if ( element.is("[title]") ) { //if just title return title
      return element.attr( "title" );
    }
 }
   });
 });
```

Comment: @Alexander the code I provided is better as you will retrieve same content over and over again for different content. This is easier so you can have different content